# Do apps created with Node JS need node js in production?

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

When apps that use Node JS packages are compiled for production, do they typically require Node JS in order to run on production, or are they compiled into runable JS (or does it vary)? What about the apps listed below?

- express (https://www.npmjs.com/package/express)
- body-parser (https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser)
- mysql (https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql)

Comment: You need a VM running Node in the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they generally need NodeJS to run on production. It is possible to use [pkg](https://github.com/zeit/pkg) to package a Node application so that it can run without Node installed, but this is meant for cases when you are distributing your application to users directly. If you are running a server, it is better just to install Node.